# How does Laravel route::controller handle camel/snake case?

Tags: routes, laravel, camelcasing

in routes.php:

```
Route::controller('account', 'AccountController');
```

in ajax -> controller:

```
POST /account/password_reset -> postPasswordReset  //not working
POST /account/passwordReset -> postPasswordReset  //not working
POST /account/password_reset -> postPassword_reset  //not working
POST /account/passwordreset -> postPasswordreset  //working
```

I was under the impression (and would prefer) the first option, but it's not behaving for me in that way. What should be happening here?

Comment: have you try inspecting your route using ```php artisan route```?

Comment: Not sure how to use this but it sounds awesome. I'm getting `Command "route" is not defined.` on my server

Comment: Have you watch https://tutsplus.com/lesson/displaying-registered-routes/

Comment: ah just need to update my laravel to 4.0.0 I guess

Comment: I know this is an old question, but for anyone coming here being confused about using artisan's route command mentioned above, the syntax is: `php artisan route:list`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Laravel 4 uses - to seperate long action names, so in this case your action would look like the following

```
public function postPasswordReset
```

and your url's to it would look like

```
/account/password-reset
```

However, I recommend using one of the built in router URL helpers, for example `HTML::linkAction()`, `URL::action()` or if you're using a form, just specify `'action' => 'YourController@YourAction'`

Docs: http://laravel.com/docs/html#opening-a-form